# References in passport

Tags: passports

Can I put my friends details in the passport as references how resides near my house and come in same police station but they are not in my neighborhood  like just a street difference is there

Comment: Please edit your question. It is not understandable now.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! Your question reads like a postmodern poem, like something Ferlinghetti would produce. What kind of passport? Who is not in your neighbourhood? The police? or your friend? What difference does it make if they live on a different street?  Please clarify. I am submitting your question to the community review as 'unclear'. You can edit and prevent closure, thanks

Comment: It vaguely sounds like you are asking about references for a passport application in some particular (unspecified) country, but nothing is clear.